# Measurement inaccuracy

Tags: signal-analysis

Does this measurement result comply with the specification or not? Why?

1. The upper limit of a test is 50 m/s and your measurement result is 46.912 ± 10 m/s.
2. The lower limit of a test is 5 mT and your measurement result is 6.1 ± 1.1 mT.
3. A test is specified such that the result must be 15 ± 0.5 kW and your measurement result is 15.4 ± 0.1 kW with a confidence level of 95%.

Comment: What does that $\pm$ suggest? Is it the standard deviation or the range?

Comment: This is probably better for the stats stack exchange. I tacitly assume the measurement errors are normally distributed and, in each case, the stated measurement result appears to be in the form sample mean ± one sample standard deviation. Then, in each of the 3 cases, how many measurements were involved in the calculations?